# Need help with my 1st IPA recipe

Tags: extract, troubleshooting, ipa, recipe

I've got a couple extract (kits) batches under my belt and now want to venture out into the unknown and create my own recipe. The following is what I've come up with after doing a bit of research. I've been reading a lot about adding late hops (20 minutes) to get a stronger hop flavor and aroma without the strong bitterness and wanted to try it for this recipe. I am also set on simcoe and amarillo cause I love the combination. Any suggestions are much appreciated. As I said, I really have no idea what the hell I'm doing or what it's gonna taste like so please help me out. Just plugging stuff into the software...

Cheers!

Rough IPA Recipe #1

Expected OG: 1.064 SG
Expected FG: 1.011 SG
Expected ABV: 7.1 %
Expected ABW: 5.5 %
Expected IBU (using Tinseth): 50.9 IBU
Expected Color (using Morey): 9.9 SRM

Boil Duration: 60.0 mins
Fermentation Temperature: 65 F

US Caramel 60L Malt 1lb

Canadian Honey Malt (Gambrinus) 4.00 oz

Extract - Light Dried Malt Extract 6lb

Sugar - Corn Sugar/Dextrose (Dry) 1lb

US Simcoe 13.0 % 1.00 oz 26.5 Loose Pellet Hops All Of Boil

US Amarillo 5.0 % 0.50 oz 3.1 Loose Pellet Hops 20 Min

US Simcoe 13.0 % 0.50 oz 8.0 Loose Pellet Hops 20 Min

US Amarillo 5.0 % 1.00 oz 3.7 Loose Pellet Hops 10 Min

US Simcoe 13.0 % 1.00 oz 9.6 Loose Pellet Hops 10 Min

US Amarillo 5.0 % 0.50 oz 0.0 Loose Pellet Hops At turn off

US Simcoe 13.0 % 0.50 oz 0.0 Loose Pellet Hops At turn off

US Amarillo 5.0 % 0.50 oz 0.0 Loose Pellet Hops Dry-Hopped

US Simcoe 13.0 % 0.50 oz 0.0 Loose Pellet Hops Dry-Hopped

Yeast US-05

Answer (score 2):

Looks good. I'd probably drop the sugar, and just add some extra DME instead. Also I probably wouldn't dry-hop with simcoe (cat pee etc.), but that's up to you.

Comment: No Way!  I think Simcoe is yummy - I dry hop with it all the time.  Some people don't like it; I never smell cat pee, to be honest.  I do agree with dropping the sugar for DME.

Comment: I say keep the sugar.  Extract is generally less fermentable than AG and the sugar will drop your FG and add to the drinkability.  I always add sugar to my extract beers.

Comment: Agreeing with Denny. 6lb of extract is plenty here, keep the sugar so this beer will end up with a lower FG.

Answer (score 1):

So are you guys saying that simcoe is a good hop to use as long as it's not used for dry hopping? I feel like everywhere I read someone is praising simcoe.  Simcoe, simcoe, simcoe...  Is using it at flameout still gonna give me "cat piss" qualities?

Comment: This might be better treated as a separate question, rather than an answer to your question.    I can smell it in other people's beers, but I don't know when they're using it to get the cat piss.  There is also an onion-y thing going on with it, which i have experienced in a black IPA kit, where it went in in the 10-15 minutes remaining range.    I think you should try it yourself and see what you think about it.

Comment: Tastes vary.  Simcoe is one of my all time favorite hops and I use it frequently and liberally.  Don't let someone talk you out of an ingredient.  Try it and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks alright to me.   I think I might increase the bittering so that you have something closer to a 1:1 bittering unit to gravity unit ratio, but it sounds like less bitter is your goal, so that's a matter of taste.

I also wouldn't use that much simcoe, but that's another matter of personal preference (it smells like cat pee to me).

I think I would double the dry hop amounts, though.   Looks like a good beer.

Comment: I've heard this "cat pee" thing before.  How does one go about learning what cat pee smells like?

Comment: You've obviously never been within 10 feet a litter box.

Comment: It's been a while...

Comment: I have never used Simcoe...but I do have two cats.  I will probably stay away from this hop now.

Comment: try it for yourself...   i'm sure it's a particular range of addition times that create it.   i used a kit that used it as a flavor addition, and i didn't notice it much.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a great recipe!  I would drop some of the 60L and use some Carafoam - and definitely drop the sugar and use DME or Pale LME.  If you've ever had the Weyerbacher Double Simcoe IPA - you'd know how great Simcoe can be in an IPA, it's in my top ten favorites of all time.